# How to scale this custom to-arrow when choosing A0 size?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, posters

I have used another arrow-tip in TikZ to replace the usual one in a document. It works, but when trying to use it for an a0poster, it doesn't scale the tip.

```
   \documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}     
    \usepackage{tikz} 
    \newcommand{\toprime}[1][]{\mathrel{\tikz \draw [-stealth, #1] (0,0) (0,0.5ex) -- (1.0em,0.5ex);}}
    \let\ToUsual\to 
    \renewcommand{\to}{\toprime}% 
      \begin{document}
     \[a\to b\] \[a\ToUsual b\]
     \end{document}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As a remedy you can add `\tikzset{every picture/.prefix style={line width=0.1ex}}` or a different value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure there are a number of ways, but here is one with `scalerel`, showing it carries through to different font sizes.

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}     
\usepackage{tikz,scalerel} 
\newcommand{\toprime}[1][]{\mathrel{\scalerel*{%
  \rule{0pt}{6pt}\tikz \draw [-stealth, #1] (0,0) (0,2pt) -- (8pt,2pt);}{X}}}
\let\ToUsual\to 
\renewcommand{\to}{\toprime}% 
\begin{document}
\[a\to b\] \[a\ToUsual b\]

\tiny\[a\to b\] \[a\ToUsual b\]
\end{document}
```

[image]